# System issues with Java 64 Bit

Tags: java, r, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Full disclosure: this is a federal computer/system so I have limited capability to make significant changes, but our federal "Enterprise" service desk of course does not know what is happening, so, I'm here.

I have a 64 bit operating system set up due to setting up ODBC connections to work with various programs which includes R 64 bit (this is the set up we were told we needed for all the systems to work). I of course also need Java 64 bit in order to use many of the R packages available nd have installed 64 bit Java multiple times, while sometimes removing and sometimes leaving 32 bit Java installed. Everything works fine for a while and I'm able to use the packages requiring Java by setting the Java environment path as necessary. No problems there.

The issue comes a few hours/one day later when my entire system shuts down with no notification at all (all programs just shut down while I'm actively working in them). The system reboots itself, 64 bit Java is uninstalled and 32 bit Java is reinstalled (regardless of whether I had uninstalled the 32 bit version or not) and I'm left to reinstall 64 bit, which works for a few hours before the whole process repeats itself.

I can't find anything anywhere for the same issue so... Anyone have any ideas? Our service desk basically just told me our systems only force reboots for Windows updates and and don't have any idea what is happening.

Edit: This is Java 1.8.0_111 although I've had the same issue with previous updates of Java 8.

Edit 2: No one else is having the same issue and are having no trouble with 64 bit Java on their computers. I'm special.

Comment: guess the software distribution system of your *federal "Enterprise"* is going wilde..

Comment: There is no sane reason to be re-installing or removing software on a restart. Windows does this to get around file locking issues, but even Windows only does this to the OS.

Comment: It might be a domain policy issue. You should ask around at serverfault.com.

Comment: BTW: If you really need a jre that wouldn't get uninstalled, and you're on a draconian system, then just deploy a local copy of the jre next to your application. If it's not installed, it shouldn't be removed...